# Need help printing just 1 decimal place

Tags: java, decimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to get my output to print to only 1 decimal place.I've tried using the `DecimalFormat` but it is messing up the alignment of my output. 
Here is what my output was before I used the `DecimalFormat`:

ID     Programs    Midterm  Final  Weighted Average

--   --------  -------  -----  -------- -------

1212   90.0     85.0    92.0    89.30000000000001      Pass

6666   60.0     80.0    90.0    78.0      Pass

7777   90.0     90.0    90.0    90.0      Pass

8888   95.0     87.0    93.0    91.8      Pass

9999   75.0     77.0    73.0    74.8      Pass

And here is what it looks like after I used the `DecimalFormat`:

ID   Programs  Midterm  Final  Weighted Average  Programs grade

--   --------     -------  -----  ----------------  --------------

1212   90.0     85.0    92.0         89.3            Pass

6666   60.0     80.0    90.0         78            Pass

7777   90.0     90.0    90.0         90            Pass

8888   95.0     87.0    93.0         91.8            Pass

9999   75.0     77.0    73.0         74.8            Pass

Here is the code I am working with:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
double Program = inputFile.nextDouble(); //Programs
double Midterm = inputFile.nextDouble(); //Midterm
double Final = inputFile.nextDouble(); //Final
double WAverage = (Program * WProgram) + (Midterm * WMidterm)+ 
(Final * WFinal);
classAve = classAve +WAverage;
NumStudents++;
String ResultsString = new String(" Fail");
if (WAverage >= 70)
ResultsString = " Pass";
System.out.println(ID +"   " + Program +"     "+ Midterm +"    "+ Final +
"             "+ df.format(WAverage) +"           " +ResultsString );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
String.format("%.1f", WAverage);
```

Instead of

```
df.format()
```

No need for DecimalFormat

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the minimum amount of decimals:

```
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by changing one character: Use `.0` instead of `.#` in your format string if you want to always display one decimal place, even if that digit is zero. Here's the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Then the first line of your code snippet would be:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
```